# Google friend connect integration for mailing lists and forums and seperate channels

Tags: chat

Google just released [Google Friend Connect](http://www.google.com/friendconnect/admin/site/overview?id=00627780894841784194&hl=en) which allows you to allow community discussion and the possibility for real-time community communication on your site.

I think it'd be really cool to integrate this with open source dev mailing lists and dev forums, to offer a more "real-time" chat discussion along with the longer email responses in the same place (at least for users of the google groups web front-end). Even stackoverflow could benefit from this (instead of checking comments and refreshing the page you could reply in real-time).

There is a service that lets you create Google Friend connect chat rooms but it doesn't seem to be able to embed in other sites called [Clackpoint](http://www.clackpoint.com/).

Mainly I'm curious if anyone has any solutions for doing the following.

1. Integrating Google Friend Connect with Google Groups (e.g. for google code projects) or other dev forums
2. If there's no direct integration with google groups is there an API or a way to "authenticate" a user to an external "Google Friend Connect" enabled community site based on their google groups membership.
3. Is there a way to support channels in Google Friend Connect to focus discussion to a particular mailing list post or forum topic (and it'd be good to integrate the chat log with that mailing list post/discussion).

Also does anyone know if Google friend connect can be configured to have "channels" or "topics" for example on a dev forum or google groups mailing list it might make sense to have a seperate real-time chat channel for a given mailing list topic or forum post. This "Google Friend connect" stuff feels very akin to Google Wave capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to embed Google Groups onto a Google Site page.

There is a good instruction at:
 http://sites.google.com/a/pjrprojects.co.uk/groupssitestips/help-with/embedding-forums

Also, you can embed Google Friend Connect onto a Blogger page.